# How can we profile memory usage of each Celery task?

Tags: python, celery, pytest, memory-profiling

I run tests using pytest which in turn runs a couple of celery tasks. But, when I use

```
mprof run --include-children py.test test.py
```

I am not able to track the memory consumed by each celery task that is running inside a celery worker. All I could see 50 MB of RAM being consumed by the py.test process (which I am able see in the mprof plot) whereas  the celery worker consumes around 600-700 MB of RAM which does not get reflected in the mprof plot. How can I plot the memory consumption of each Celery task triggered by the py.test?

P.S I use memory profiler package to profile the memory consumption of a python script.

Comment: I am guessing you would be spawning some celery tasks from your pytest and thus they go through AMQP and into another process space? If so profilig the task creator (pytest) won't give memory profile on the task consumer (celery)

Answer (score 0):

What about `--multiprocess` flag?
https://github.com/pythonprofilers/memory_profiler#tracking-forked-child-processes

Comment: Even when you use multidprocess flag you can only see the plots of different child processes running but you don't get to see how much memory is consumed by each of the named tasks that are attached to a celery worker.